# Sound output isn't working

Tags: drivers, sound

I replaced Windows with Ubuntu, but I have a problem about sound. I can't listen music. How i can update my sound driver?

Answer (score 0):

You should go to your computer manufacturers' website to download the required sound drivers. They must be Linux compatible.

You could also change the PulseAudio and ALSA sound services configurations so that the sound could, you know, sound better.